# Run predefined formulas in R with one function

Tags: r, formula

for my project I need to run many different models but similar at the same time since just one variable changes, I would like to make the process as easy and line-consuming as possible (my R script is quite long at this moment...)

```
data(mtcars)   
Model1 <- formula(mpg ~ cyl + disp)    
Model2 <- formula(mpg ~ cyl + hp)    
Model3 <- formula(mpg ~ cyl + wt)    
Model4 <- formula(mpg ~ cyl + qsec)  
All.Models <- cbind(Model1, Model2, Model3, Model4)
```

Is there a way to run all the formulas, specifically the All.Models, on a model function (lm(), aov(), etc.) and specify the dataset (here is on mtcars, but I have different datasets for the same models)?

I tried with the following two versions:

```
All.Ouput1 <- lm(lapply(All.Models), data=mtcars)
```

Or

```
All.Output2 <- lapply(All.Models, lm(All.Models, data=mtcars))
```

In the first one it runs for some minutes until I had to stop it manually, and the second one gives me an error

Also the `str(All.Models)` is a list where is model takes 3 lines

```
str(All.Models)
List of 12
 $ : symbol ~
 $ : symbol mpg
 $ : language cyl + disp
 $ : symbol ~
 $ : symbol mpg
 $ : language cyl + hp
 $ : symbol ~
 $ : symbol mpg
 $ : language cyl + wt
 $ : symbol ~
 $ : symbol mpg
 $ : language cyl + qsec
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 3 4
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "Model1" "Model2" "Model3" "Model4"
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
data(mtcars)   
F1 <- formula(mpg ~ cyl + disp)    
F2 <- formula(mpg ~ cyl + hp)    
F3 <- formula(mpg ~ cyl + wt)    
F4 <- formula(mpg ~ cyl + qsec)  
All.formulas <- list(F1, F2, F3, F4) 

All.models <- lapply(All.formulas,lm,data=mtcars)
lapply(All.models,summary)
```

Formulas are not really models.

The solution with apparent regression calls:

```
customF <- function(x) {

    out.model <- lm(x,data=mtcars)
    out.model$call <- x
    return(out.model)
}


All.models <- lapply(All.formulas,customF)
lapply(All.models,summary)
```

There probably is a more elegant way to do it, but this works too.

Comment: YES! thank you! One question, an aesthetic issue, is there a way in the summaries to get the formula of the model on the top so that I know which model's output I see?

Comment: @Pulse Edited to add what you ask.